# How do I create optional "options" in a facade?

Tags: scala.js

I am trying to create a facade for the bootstrap popover function that can take up to 11 optional parameters.  In my scalajs code I would like to only pass in the parameters I need to override from library maintained sensible defaults ie: `PopoverOptions(animation = false)` just like I would do in javascript.  This seems to be the recommend way to make a facade but it makes all the parameters required:

```
trait PopoverOptions extends js.Object {
  val animation: String = js.native
  val container: String = js.native
  val content: String = js.native
  ... 
}

object PopoverOptions {
  def apply(animation: String, container: String, content: String, ...): PopoverOptions = {
    js.Dynamic.literal(animation=animation, container= container, content = content, ...).asInstanceOf[PopoverOptions ]
  }
}
```

It looks like one way is to define an apply for every possible permutation of parameters but when there are lots of override parameters this gets excessive quick:

```
def apply(animation: String): ...
def apply(container: String): ... 
def apply(animation: String, container: String): ...
...
```

What is the idiomatic way to create an options parameter facade with lots of override parameters that typically have sensible library maintained defaults?

Note: both answers have pros/cons so to decide it might be helpful to see both ways without leaving SO so here is a summary of JSOptionBuilder method:

```
import org.querki.jquery.JQuery
import org.querki.jsext._

@js.native
trait PopoverOptions extends js.Object
object PopoverOptions extends PopoverOptionBuilder(noOpts)
class PopoverOptionBuilder(val dict:OptMap) extends JSOptionBuilder[PopoverOptions, PopoverOptionBuilder](new PopoverOptionBuilder(_))
{
  def animation(v:String) = jsOpt("animation", v)
  def container(v:String) = jsOpt("container", v)
  def content(v:String) = jsOpt("content", v)
  ...
}
```

To use:   `PopoverOptions.animation("yay").container("container").content("bottom")._result`

Comment: Yep, just so.  One note on that last line, though: the explicit _result *usually* isn't necessary -- there's an implicit conversion in jsext that automatically extracts it when you use this in a context that is expecting PopoverOptions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The alternative approach is to use JSOptionBuilder, which was created for this purpose. (I write many jQuery facades, and they *always* have this problem.) JSOptionBuilder isn't quite as critical as it used to be (this was a major problem before the "|" operator was introduced), but I still find it's usually the best way to deal with complex facades.

Here's [the full description of this approach](https://www.querki.net/u/jducoeur/scala-notes/#!Creating-a-Scalajs-Facade-for-a-jQuery-Widget). (Note that that's enormously detailed -- the first half is the key stuff, and the rest deals with all the somewhat-common edge cases.)

Comment: Thanks Justin for the time it took to write up the full description.  This approach makes it easy to do complex facades with union types, etc:    def animation(v:Boolean | Int) = jsOpt("animation", v)

Answer (score 2):

You can use Scala's default values for parameters, combined with `js.UndefOr`s of the types of elements, like this:

```
object PopoverOptions {
  @inline
  def apply(
      animation: js.UndefOr[String] = js.undefined,
      container: js.UndefOr[String] = js.undefined,
      content: js.UndefOr[String] = js.undefined,
      ...): PopoverOptions = {
    val result = js.Dynamic.literal()
    animation.foreach(result.animation = _)
    container.foreach(result.container = _)
    content.foreach(result.content = _)
    ...
    result.asInstanceOf[PopoverOptions]
  }
}
```

Then you can call with `PopoverOptions(animation = false)`, as you wished.

It's a bit verbose at definition site, but it will get the job done.

Comment: I love that this makes my end result look like scala and it requires no libraries.  Just one thing though, what would I do to make it handle union types ex: container could be "String | Boolean"?

Comment: Use a `js.UndefOr[String | Boolean]`. In 0.6.5 the illicites aren't quite good enough to infer the whole conversion, so you'll need to ascribe at call site with `: String | Boolean`. This is fixed in the upcoming 0.6.6.